# Как нарисовать окружность заданного радиуса линиями?

Tags: imagick, php, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Совершенно не шарю в математике, но в своих опытах столкнулся с тем, что нужно нарисовать на канве круг линией. К примеру, в библиотеке Imagick для php у объекта класса ImageDraw есть метод line(x1, y1. x2. y2). Я не прошу готовой реализации, просто нужна либо формула, либо кусок алгоритма, либо, в какую сторону гуглить)

Comment: Что значит рисовать круг линией? 
Что вы думаете в Imagick нет функции ImagickDraw::circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Алгоритм Брезенхэма](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) же!

Comment: Благодарю)

Comment: рисовать круг попиксельно в интерпретаторе это же медленно

Comment: @sercxjo, скажу больше, у меня интерпретатор, который рисует круг встроен в интерпретатор php :D

Comment: @nolka, разве нет штатных средств рисования круга?

Comment: @Flammable, Я хочу контроллировать разрешение, с которым рисуется круг. Круг можно нарисовать, к примеру, ровным таким, сглаженным, а можно нарисовать его, к примеру, 10 линиями, он получится не сглаженным, а угловатым)

Comment: @nolka, это не разрешение, а количество разибиений.

Comment: @Flammable, спасибо, буду знать)